# Unable to get Wordpress's apply_filters('site_url') to return a https scheme

Tags: filters, ssl, site-url

I am in the middle of migrating a Wordpress site to being entirely `https://`, but  I am having trouble with the login page.

The **login page itself is loading with the `https://` scheme, but the form action is pointing to the insecure, `http://` version of the page**, which is causing it to simply redirect back to the `https://` version (I'm assuming it's because my `.htaccess` is redirecting http traffic to its https counterpart.)

In wp-login.php, the following code sets the form action:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">
```

Seemingly, the problematic function is the `site_url()` function, as it is what is returning the `http://` version of the site.

I looked into the function itself, and the function calls are made in this order:

```
site_url -> get_site_url -> set_url_scheme -> apply_filter -> *return*
```

Tracing my way through this call stack, I noticed that the only time the scheme gets set back to `http://` is when the apply_filter function is called.

I have explicitly set `site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'https')`, and even that is returning a `http://` scheme.

I am hoping that someone has an idea about what is going on here, because I'm not seeing why Wordpress isn't allowing me to use `https://` for this. It seems to be working almost everywhere else, as all of my relative links for my css and js are loading https versions.

**Note:** I have set `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` and my wordpress `site_url` and `home_url` are set to their `https://` versions in the options table.

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and/or tried this with a default theme?

Answer (score 0):

The source of this problem was a mu-plugin that our vendor left in, but should have been removed. Anyway, the lesson here is to **always check your plugins.**